# How to disable an instance?

Tags: azerothcore

I want to disable an instance in AzerothCore but I don't know how.

It's for a progressive server.

*Question asked in our Discord, the user had not tried anything.*

Comment: can't be more specific, and i answered my own question -__-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable maps with this the table `disables` in the `world` database

http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/disables

Example by [Shard-MW](https://github.com/shard-mw):

```
INSERT INTO disables (2, 631, 15, 0, 0, "Raid - ICC - Disable");
```

If you want to disable a dungeon, replace 15 by 3. 15 is for raids